# Gatsby "Creating Pages from Data Programatically" Doesn't Work

Tags: javascript, graphql, gatsby

I'm trying this. But with `String!` gets the error, `Errors:
  Variable "$slug" of required type "String!" was not provided.` even query(the below works well on localhost:8000/___graphql). Then I tried `String` without string. Then the error is gone, but I always get the same content which is markdown's info.

Does anyone have any ideas to solve this issue?

my repo: https://github.com/koji/portfolio

Thank you in advance,

error

```
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby";

export const getPostData = () => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(
    graphql`
      query getPostData($slug: String!) {
        markdownRemark(fields: { slug: { eq: $slug } }) {
          frontmatter {
            title
            date
          }
          html
        }
      }
    `);
  return data.markdownRemark;
};
```

returns the same content

```
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby";

export const getPostData = () => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(
    graphql`
      query getPostData($slug: String) {
        markdownRemark(fields: { slug: { eq: $slug } }) {
          frontmatter {
            title
            date
          }
          html
        }
      }
    `);
  return data.markdownRemark;
};
```

trying to get the title of a markdown file

```
import * as React from "react";
import Layout from "../components/layout";
import { getPostData } from "../components/hooks/getPost";

const Blog = () => {
  const data = getPostData();
  console.log(data);
  return (
    <Layout>
      <h1>{data.frontmatter.title}</h1>
      <p>{data.frontmatter.date}</p>
      {data.html}

    </Layout>
  );

};

export default Blog;
```

gatsby-node.js

```js
const path = require("path");

// onCreateNode API
module.exports.onCreateNode = ({node, actions}) => {
  const { createNodeField } = actions;
  // console.log(node);
  if(node.internal.type === 'MarkdownRemark') {
    const slug = path.basename(node.fileAbsolutePath, '.md');
    createNodeField({
      node,
      name: 'slug',
      value: slug
    });
  }
}

module.exports.createPages = async({ graphql, actions}) => {
  const { createPage } = actions;
  const blogTemplate = path.resolve('./src/templates/blog.tsx');
  const res = await graphql(`
    query {
      allMarkdownRemark {
        edges {
          node {
            fields {
              slug
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `);
   res.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.forEach(({node}) => {
     createPage({
       component: blogTemplate,
       path: `/blog/${node.fields.slug}`,
       context: {
         slug: node.fields.slug,
       }
     });
   })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to use a regular page query in your post template, i.e `export const query = graphql...`

The reason is that `useStaticQuery` & `<StaticQuery>` just won't receive the `context` you've passed into `createPage`.

[Official docs: How Static Query Differ from Page Query](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/static-query/#how-staticquery-differs-from-page-query)

Comment: I see, Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi, I'm getting the same error although I'm using the page query, but the error only occurs in the build process. Page rendering works after compilation. My context is empty when building. Any ideas?

Comment: @kentrh hard to tell without more info about your build, though the fact that it only occurs during build is an important clue. Would you post a new question with more info of your build?